# Why passport.authenticate is not calling?

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, passport.js

this is my first question and I´m kinda tired to search...maybe it´s a newbies mistake but I´ve tried everything to solve it but didn´t found the answer.

I´ve built the passport new local strategy like this:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: "username",
    passwordField: "password"
  }, async (username, password, done) => {

    const user = await User.findOne({username: username});

    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Este usuario no existe.' });
    } 
    else {
      const match = await user.matchPassword(password);
      if(match) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Usuario/Contraseña no correctos.' });
      }
    }
  }));
```

And this is the way I call him:

```
router.post("/users/login", async (req, res) => {
    dni = req.body.username;
    usuario = await User.findOne({username: dni});
    idUser = usuario._id;
    configuracion = await Config.findOne({idUsuario: idUser});
    delStatus = configuracion.deleteStatus;
    banStatus = configuracion.banStatus; 
    if(configuracion){
        if(banStatus){
            req.flash("errors_msg", "Su usuario se encuentra bloqueado de nuestra aplicación, contacte con soporte para más información");
            res.redirect("/");
        }
        else if(delStatus){
            req.flash("errors_msg", "Este usuario está dado de baja de nuestra plataforma, en caso de error contacte con soporte");
            res.redirect("/");
        }
        else{
            passport.authenticate("local", function (user, error, info) {
                console.log("2");
                console.log(info);
                if(error){
                    console.log(error);
                    req.flash("errors_msg", "ERROR: Usuario o contraseña incorrectos")
                    res.redirect("/users/login");
                }
                if(!user){
                    req.flash("errors_msg", "ERROR: Usuario o contraseña incorrectos")
                    res.redirect("/users/login");
                }
                req.logIn(user, function (err) {
                    if(error){
                        return next(err);
                    }
                    res.redirect("/");
                })
            });
        }
    }
    else{
        if(usuario){
            id = consultaUsuario._id;
            res.redirect("/users/verify?=" + id);
        }
        else{
            req.flash("errors_msg", "Este usuario no existe, registrese o en caso de error, consulte con nuestro servicio de atención al cliente");
            res.redirect("/users/register");
        }
    }
});
```

But passport is not launched anyway...

Anyone can help me? Thanks in advance!

---

Edit 1:

@davidmwhynot this is the most accurate:

LocalStrategy:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy({
    usernameField: "username",
    passwordField: "password",
    passReqToCallback: true
  },  async (res, username, password, done) => {

    const user = await User.findOne({username: username});
    idUsuario = user._id;
    const configuracion = await Config.findOne({idUsuario: idUsuario});
    if(configuracion){
      if (configuracion.banStatus) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Su usuario se encuentra bloqueado de nuestra aplicación, contacte con soporte para más información"});
      }
      if (configuracion.deleteStatus) {
        return done(null, false, { message: "Este usuario está dado de baja de nuestra plataforma, en caso de error contacte con soporte"});
      }
    }
    if (!user) {
      return done(null, false, { message: 'Este usuario no existe.' });
    } 
    else if(!configuracion){
        user.isConfig = false;
        return user;
    }
    else {
      const match = await user.matchPassword(password);
      if(match) {
        return done(null, user);
      } else {
        return done(null, false, { message: 'Usuario/Contraseña no correctos.' });
      }
    }
  }));
```

And this the login code:

```
    router.post("/users/login", passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: true
}), async (req, res) => {
         // This is not executed anyway, can´t see any param or even see a 
        //console.log
});
```

I´ve tried a lot of things, but...no one successfull, even tried `passReqToCallback: true` on localStrategy but not successfull too

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add your authentication strategy as *middleware* to your login route:

```js
router.post(
  '/users/login',
  passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/',
    failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    failureFlash: 'Invalid username or password.'
  }),
  async (req, res) => {
    // now, you don't need to query the database for your user
    // it should be available on the request already:
    var idUser = req.user.id;
  }
);
```

You should also move the logic that is checking if the user is banned to your local strategy.

---

Edit: Here is an updated local strategy that includes all of your logic for checking if a user has a configuration and is not banned.

Edit 2:

```js
router.post(
    '/users/login',
    passport.authenticate('local', {
        successRedirect: '/',
        failureRedirect: '/users/login',
    }),
    async (req, res) => {
        if (!req.user.configuration) {
            //const id = consultaUsuario._id;
            req.logOut(req.user);
            const id = req.user._id;
            req.user = null;

            res.redirect('/users/verify?=' + id);
        } else {
            res.redirect('/');
        }
    }
);

passport.use(
    new LocalStrategy(
        {
            usernameField: 'username',
            passwordField: 'password',
        },
        async (username, password, done) => {
            const user = await User.findOne({ username: username });

            if (!user) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Este usuario no existe.',
                });
            }

            const match = await user.matchPassword(password);

            if (!match) {
                return done(null, false, {
                    message: 'Usuario/Contraseña no correctos.',
                });
            }

            const configuracion = await Config.findOne({
                idUsuario: user._id,
            });

            if (!configuracion) {
                user.configuration = false;
            } else {
                const delStatus = configuracion.deleteStatus;
                const banStatus = configuracion.banStatus;

                user.configuration = true;

                if (banStatus) {
                    done(null, false, {
                        message:
                            'Su usuario se encuentra bloqueado de nuestra aplicación, contacte con soporte para más información',
                    });
                } else if (delStatus) {
                    done(null, false, {
                        message:
                            'Este usuario está dado de baja de nuestra plataforma, en caso de error contacte con soporte',
                    });
                }
            }

            done(null, user);
        }
    )
);
```

Comment: Okey, it works but have a last step to solve it: 

How I can redirect/send params from my new local strategy to the authentication function? 

I want to make verify the users that exist but don´t have a configuration

Comment: I'll update my answer with a different local strategy.

Comment: No, not works properly, it login every user even if they are blocked or unsubscribed from the platform, I will check it all again

Comment: I´ve done some test but...no good results @davidmwhynot the async function on the passport.authentication is not called, can´t send nothing there and can´t see req.params that are there, it logsin in any case

Comment: still not working properly, the most accurate answer was the first one, the only problem was that cannot redirect the user to the verification page, the rest worked fine

Comment: @B2DAW Ahh. What do you mean by original? Can you update the question with that code (the code that was most accurate)?

Comment: I´ve updated my question adding the new code, check it out (I´ve tested a lot of things but not successfull at all)

Comment: Try changing `async (res, username, password, done) => {` to `async (username, password, done) => {` and see if that helps anything.

Comment: I´ve tried and this is the response: 

`(node:7180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: CastError: Cast to string failed for value "IncomingMessage`  and `node:7180) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function 
without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)`

Comment: I´ve found a workable solution, but is without redirection, so I will close the question and really thanks a lot for your help, were so helpfull ! <3